# Insert into specific columns of table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

As per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9481, inserting into specific columns of Hive is supported. The syntax as per this link is:
Insert into target(colA, colB) select colX,colY from source;

However, when I try executing the same in Hive, I get the error:

**Semantic Exception: '[colA, colB] in insert schema specification are not found among regular columns of default.target nor dynamic partitions.**

How can I insert values in Hive by specifying a column list ?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hive supports insert with column list specified. 
The mistake I was making was that I was referencing the column names as they were in the create table statement of my script.
This was rectified by replacing this list with lowercase names of the columns used in my table.
Also, I added the keyword table which is, although, optional.
Syntax:

`INSERT INTO TABLE target(cola,colb,colc) select colx,coly,colz from source;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would also need to put word partition after target table name.

Example : INSERT INTO TABLE target **PARTITION**(cola,colb,colc) select colx,coly,colz from 
source;

Else we will notice same error as logged in original post